# unable to pass R CMD check in windows due to i386 build

Tags: r, package, rcpp, cran

I wish to submit  my R package to CRAN that  uses `Rcpp` and `RcppGSL`.My problem is that I am unable to build a  package that pass `R CMD check` in win-builder. My understanding is that because the `i386` package is built,but not installed and checked during `R CMD check`. The `x64` package builds and passes the checks (when I run check with --no--multiarch). My understanding is a bit flawed, since I had limited time to get this windows build working at all for 64-bit.
 This is the `Makevars.win.gen`

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = $(GSL_CFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)/include" -I"$(LIB_GSL)/include/gsl" -I../inst/include  -I../inst -Wall -Wno-unused-but-set-variable  -Wno-long-long -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated -pedantic -pthread -fPIC -O2 -g
ARCH=x64
ifeq "$(WIN)" "64"
ARCH= i386
else
ARCH= x64
endif
RCPPGSL_LDFLAGS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/$(R_ARCH_BIN)/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
GRAPHM_OBJ =  ./algorithm_ca.o ./algorithm_ext.o ./algorithm_fsol.o  ./algorithm_iden.o ./algorithm_lp.o ./algorithm.o ./algorithm_path.o ./algorithm_qcv.o ./algorithm_rand.o ./algorithm_rank.o ./algorithm_umeyama.o ./algorithm_unif.o ./experiment.o ./graph.o ./hungarian.o  ./rpc.o
GRAPHM_OBJ_REL = $(addprefix ./graphm/,$(GRAPHM_OBJ) )

PKG_LIBS = $(LDFLAGS) -L"$(LIB_GSL)\lib"$(R_ARCH_BIN) $(RCPPGSL_LDFLAGS)   $(GSL_LIBS) -lgsl -lgslcblas

CXX ?= g++
SHVER= 1
VPATH= ./graphm:./graphm-0.52


SOURCES=  graphmatch_rcpp.cpp RcppExports.cpp
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL)

#all: $(SHLIB) $(OBJECTS)
$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS)
#all:  $(ALLFILES) ../inst/libgraphm.a
#   cd graphm && $(MAKE)
#   $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)   $(OBJECTS)  ../inst/libgraphm.a $(PKG_LIBS)

./experiment.o:   experiment.cpp experiment.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c experiment.cpp  -o ./experiment.o
./rpc.o:   rpc.cpp rpc.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c rpc.cpp  -o ./rpc.o
./graph.o:   graph.cpp graph.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c graph.cpp  -o ./graph.o
./hungarian.o:   hungarian.cpp hungarian.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS)  -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c hungarian.cpp  -o ./hungarian.o
./algorithm.o:   algorithm.cpp algorithm.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm.cpp  -o ./algorithm.o
#graph matching algorithms
./algorithm_ca.o: algorithm_ca.cpp algorithm_ca.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_ca.cpp -o ./algorithm_ca.o
./algorithm_path.o: algorithm_path.cpp algorithm_path.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_path.cpp -o ./algorithm_path.o
./algorithm_ext.o:   algorithm_ext.cpp algorithm_ext.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_ext.cpp  -o ./algorithm_ext.o
./algorithm_fsol.o:   algorithm_fsol.cpp algorithm_fsol.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_fsol.cpp  -o ./algorithm_fsol.o
./algorithm_iden.o:   algorithm_iden.cpp algorithm_iden.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_iden.cpp  -o ./algorithm_iden.o
./algorithm_lp.o:   algorithm_lp.cpp algorithm_lp.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_lp.cpp  -o ./algorithm_lp.o
./algorithm_qcv.o:   algorithm_qcv.cpp algorithm_qcv.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_qcv.cpp  -o ./algorithm_qcv.o
./algorithm_rand.o:   algorithm_rand.cpp algorithm_rand.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS)  -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_rand.cpp  -o ./algorithm_rand.o
./algorithm_rank.o:   algorithm_rank.cpp algorithm_rank.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_rank.cpp  -o ./algorithm_rank.o
./algorithm_umeyama.o:   algorithm_umeyama.cpp algorithm_umeyama.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_umeyama.cpp  -o ./algorithm_umeyama.o
./algorithm_unif.o:   algorithm_unif.cpp algorithm_unif.h
        cd graphm && $(CXX) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) -I"$(LIB_GSL)\include" -c algorithm_unif.cpp  -o ./algorithm_unif.o

ALLOBJ: $(OBJECTS) $(GRAPHM_OBJ)

ALLFILES: $(OBJECTS) $(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL) ../inst/libgraphm.a



../inst/libgraphm.a: RcppExports.o $(GRAPHM_OBJ)
    ar -rvs ../inst/libgraphm.a $(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL)


clean: cleana cleanb

cleana:
    rm $(OBJECTS)
cleanb:
    rm $(GRAPHM_OBJ_REL)

#.PHONY: all test clean
```

Incidentally, I am using this configure.win to pass the right flags to Makevars.win. But this is really unnecessary ,since I removed @GSL_LIBS@ from Makevars.win.gen. Is this the reason i386 build is not installed during R CMD check?

```
ifeq "$(WIN)" "64"
R_ARCH_BIN="/x64"
else
R_ARCH_BIN="/i386"
endif
GSL_CFLAGS=`"${R_HOME}/bin$(R_ARCH_BIN)/Rscript.exe" -e "require(RcppGSL);RcppGSL:::CFlags()"`
GSL_LIBS=`"${R_HOME}/bin$(R_ARCH_BIN)/Rscript.exe"  -e "require(RcppGSL);RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
sed -e "s|@GSL_LIBS@|${GSL_LIBS}|" \
-e "s|@GSL_CFLAGS@|${GSL_CFLAGS}|" \
src/Makevars.win.gen > src/Makevars.win
```

Any auxiliary information that is relevant for building a multi-arch R package that is dependent on pre-built windows libraries would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your starting assumptions are wrong, methinks, and you may be making this too hard.  I think it is worth stepping back:

In order to *locally* build multi-arch, you actually need a proper multi-arch setup locally.  That would imply 32 and 64 bit builds of the GSL.

But you don't have to build locally -- you can submit your sources to both

- win-builder
- R Hub

both of which can run one or several Windows builds for you!  I use them before every upload.

Also note that you don't necessarily need a `Makevars.win` all that complicated.  My RcppZiggurat package (on CRAN) just has these two instructions:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" \ 
           -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()")
```

(and I added the linebreak by hand).

Lastly, RcppGSL has four reverse Depends so you have four working examples to study.  Eg mvabund does

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I. -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS=-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Comment: Some of the complication is due to the C library that is wrapped around the package. I want to build the package simultaneously with the C library. The rest of the complication is due to my weak understanding of the native code and R package building process which I am trying to solve.

Comment: I was about to comment on that.  The Makefile looks the part, but your question didn't say!  But your diificulties are, I think, almost entirely due to that.  Try to simplify this as much as you can -- maybe just include all of that library in `src/`.

Comment: (and I added the linebreak by hand). What do you mean by that ?

Comment: PKG_LIBS is really one line. For the post, I broke it into two.  With a linebreak.  By hand.

Comment: sorry, your comment made me think  there was another complication that I did not understand.

Comment: I was able to get the separate builds for i386 and x64 which passes the win-builder checks. I am getting a segmentation fault from gsl blas call when the  R example runs on  my local machine for i386. I get no such error in the win-builder build. But as you said this is probably my local package building is not multiarch-proof .

Comment: I will try to reduce some of the complexity in Makevars.win . This has been a good learning experience, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Second the learning experience thought.  Wrapping a library is not trivial.  I would almost suggest trying that by itself.  Rcpp is pretty easy these days and you can deal with that afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The existence of configure.win in the package source tree forces only the main architecture to be built, R CMD check fails with a message like

```
 <package> is not installed for architecture -- i386
```

unless --no-multi-arch is present. Since CRAN building process for windows checks both architectures (i386, and x64) , R CMD checks  fail during CRAN submission process, even though local R CMD checks with -no-multi-arch may be successful.

Comment: Good catch.  When I needed it, I stuck some arch-dependent 'configuration' (here: file-fetching) into the Makevars.win itself -- see eg [here](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/Makevars.win)